# Feedback on reviews

Tags: discussion

Is there a way to get feedback on the reviews we have done?

Other than the audit feedback (that I see very infrequently) are there
statistics as to how my reviews compare to my peers reviews?  This kind of feedback would help me know if any of my votes are in the majority, especially in the triage queue.

Comment: I'd say.... no?  You could always star certain questions you reviewed and look them up later to see what happened with them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also go directly to the History Page from the Reviews tab.

In this case, for Triage: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/history

This will show you all your reviews by time. Clicking the *Action Taken* column brings up the same review. In addition, you can see your skipped reviews if you wish to do so.

This interface is also friendlier in terms of showing how much you vote a certain way. For example, I have a littany of *Should be Improved* with just a dab of *Looks OK*, and almost no *Unsalvageable*.

Comment: This is close to what Im looking for.  By clicking on the triage selection, I can see the three other votes, and how bad I am at reviewing....

Comment: @StuartSiegler To be fair, Triage is by far the most subjective review tree. I'd weigh that the only way you "win at the game" is to vote *Should be Improved* every time.

Comment: I'm not going to learn to be a better reviewer, If I don't know when I doing it "wrong" ;-)  I was hoping for more of a [- + + + ]  view -- "3 of your peers thought this was OK" ... instant feedback.  Just trying to provide value

Answer (score 6):

You can go through your profile, Activity tab, Reviews sub-tab ([direct-link goodness](https://stackoverflow.com/users/664479/stuart-siegler?tab=activity&sort=reviews)), and then go through your reviews by clicking on the action taken (i.e. "Looks Good", "Close", etc.)

If a question or answer was deleted, though, you'll only be able to see it if you have 10K+ reputation.

Comment: The ./triage/history is close.  I can click on each of my recommendations, I can see the other's votes...